# Onload function not working for a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script:

```
<script>
function load_thankyou()
{
    alert('hii');
    var delay = 1000; //Your delay in milliseconds
    var URL = 'thankyou.php';
    setTimeout(function()
                { 
                  window.location = URL; 
                }, delay);
}
</script>
```

The function is called in the following manner...

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
        if($error_flag == 0)
        {?>

    <a class="close" href="#" onload="load_thankyou()">×</a>
<?php
        }
    }?>
```

But it seems, somehow the onload() function is not working..

Comment: are you sure that a `a`-tag has a onload property ?

Comment: I don't know. May because they don't have a answere and getting angry.

Comment: The `onload` event is fired just on these elements: `<body>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input type="image">`, `<link>`, `<script>`,  and `<style>`.

Comment: like i sayed, a-tag has no onload. But you could use it like I posted. That's kind a manuel onload for a-tags. or lets say for exact this a-tag :)

Comment: Instead of wasting your time moaning about voting (which is anonymous), focus on learning the tools you're trying to use. If you come here asking people to debug your code, you'll definitely get downvotes.

Comment: @MelanciaUK    yeah, off course... SO is supposed to help people.. But the behave we generally get from some users is that of arrogance and pride.... instead of making people learn or help, they just concentrate their attention on punishing every "not upto mark question"...

Comment: Stick to the site rules and you'll be OK.

Comment: One reason for the downvotes could be the obvious question of "why would you want to use onload for this?" Why not just call the function rather than trying to pigeonhole the function into a link tag and then call it onload?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to give your link only a class and href to # (what links to none) like:

```
<a class="close" href="#" >×</a>
```

And your JS could look like:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //check if close element exists. If yes, execute the function
        if($('.close').length() > 0) load_thankyou();
    });

    function load_thankyou()
    {
        alert('hii');
        var delay = 1000; //Your delay in milliseconds
        var URL = 'thankyou.php';
        setTimeout(function()
                    { 
                      window.location = URL; 
                    }, delay);
    }

</script>
```

this waits until page is load and check if the a-tag exists and if yes it will execute the function. kind of like a onload for a-tags

Comment: I just edited my post because I realised that the link wasn't very handy like it was build :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but, what is the practical point of this? Why would you not just simply call `load_thankyou();`  in your `$(document).ready(function(){});` and be done with it. That's probably the reason for the downvotes. It works but seems completely unnecessary

Comment: because you may have different sides and you don't want to load this on every page :) may you have 100 pages and just want it to be executed if element exists. Of course you could check if element exists and execut it than.

Comment: all that logic can be accomplished  with any number of checks before you call `load_thankyou();` that is no reason to write the function to a link that will never serve any purpose other than to hold the name of your function while a separate (equally useless) function clicks said link

Answer (score 0):

onload property is only working with "body" tag,
you can not use anywhere else.
for implementing in  tag you need to do it with javascript in "a" tag's click event on loading

you can can "a" tag's click event in body load event through javascript

Comment: thanks alot Saswat... i am appreciating your feedback

Comment: "onload property is only working with "body" tag,
you can not use anywhere else." is not correct. Onload is valid for the following tags: <body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> and <style>

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would just call the function rather than trying to pigeonhole the function into a link tag and then call it onload

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
        if($error_flag == 0)
        {
           echo 'load_thankyou()';

        }
    }?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use like this if you want to use the function when clicked:

```
<a class="close" href="javascript:load_thankyou()">×</a>
```

---

Or, if you want to execute the code immediately after a tag is ready then use your code after the html, I would prefer to use it in ending of closing body:

```
<script>
load_thankyou();
</script>
</body>
```

In your case, you may do:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
        if($error_flag == 0)
        {?>

    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
    <script>
     load_thankyou();
    </script>
<?php
        }
    }?>
```

onload is executed only for document truly to say all images are loaded you do this `<body onload="">` but with `a` tag you can't do...

Comment: but this will be executed on click, so actually its not a onload :)

Comment: You don't need to change the `href` here. Especially point it to a `Javascript` call, which is bad when it comes to SEO.