# HTML onload Event in link element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Based on w3schools, HTML onload  attribute supports link tag so I'm trying to load a javascript function when the link is loaded. The problem is the onload attribute won't fire the function. There's no errors. Why is this? I'm sorry for noob question.

I tried using onload in body and it works. But when I try to use onload in link tags like link or a tags it doesn't work.

```
    <a onload='myFunction("Hello");'> Test <a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(value){
    console.log(value);
    }
    </script>
```

I need to run a function after the link loads. In this example, it should print "Hello" in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp onload event attribute can be used with tags:

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> and <style>
```

You are **NOT** using `<link>` tag. You are using anchor(`<a>`) tag on which this attribute is not supported!
`<link>` tag is used to link an external resource to the document. For example CSS file.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

---

Comment: I see, I got confused between those two tags. Thanks for the clarification. I think I need to take some rest.

Comment: @JeremiahEdwardMedel No problem, mate!

Answer (score 1):

a tag hasn’t got a onload property. See the link in my comments.

```
The onload event is fired just on these elements:  
   <body>, <frame>, <iframe>,
 <img>, <input type="image">,
 <link>, <script>, and <style>
```

Comment: Already tried link tag but still doesn't work.
    <link onload='myFunction("Hello");'> Test <link>

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687111/onload-function-not-working-for-a-href

Answer (score 0):

`onload` is most often used within the  element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.). However, it can be used on other elements as well (see "Supported HTML tags" below).

`Supported HTML tags: <body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> and <style>`

Comment: Yes that's what I read from w3schools. I tried the link tag but still doesn't work.